# Don't know how to use "if in" in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

i'm doing "the feeling lucky project" from "automate the boring stuff with python" which i have  to open 5 new tabs in the browser based on what you search on google. Using bs4 i managed to get all the links related with search on a list named "links" which looked like this:

[image: list]

and i noticed that before the '#' is the link i actually need, so i tried

```
for i in links:
if '#' in i:
    print(links.index(i))
```

and i would get index of '#' - 1, so i could get the link. But when i run the code it just prints 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1. Which is the index of the first '#' and my loop is stuck there. Can someone explain me why?

Thank you!

Comment: `'i'` is the text string "i", unrelated to your variable `i`. You might be looking for the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Comment: sure, it wasn't like this thank you!, i'll edit it. But even using the i as a variable, it returns 1, 1, 1,1, 1.  I'll check enumerate, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the index of the first '#'

It should be the index of the first `'i'` based on your (original} code

This is checking if the link *string* contains # *as a character*, which indirectly ensures its in the list, I guess... But likely not what you want

```
for i in links:
   if '#' in i:
```

If you just want **one result**, remove the loop and use the correct character

```
idx = links.index('#')
if idx >= 0:
    print(idx, links[idx])
else:
    print('not found')
```

`'#' in links` just returns true or false, it won't tell you where it is

If you want **all** matches, that would be this (though just a list of #, which seems pointless)

```
[x for x in links if x == '#']
```

If you want **all links before #**, you can get the links directly, or you can append in the index as well

```
res = [] 
for i in range(1,len(links)):  # start one ahead because we're subtracting later 
    if links[i] == '#':
        res.append(links[i-1])
print(res)
```

Comment: Ok i eddited my comment, cuz when i posted you answered my question. When i ran your code to get all links before #. I got this error "for i, x in range(len(links) - 1):
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Comment: Using index function makes a nested loop, which you don't need. As commented, use enumerate. `[(i, x,) for i, x in enumerate(links) where x == '#']`

Comment: Oh now it's fixed!! Can i ask why you use this "range(len(links) - 1)"?   Thank you!!

Comment: Use range to go from 0 to the parameter, which in this case is the end of the list. I should remove the -1 since it's not needed here